# JTextField enable DnD, but not able to edit

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I want to be able to drag and drop a selection from a JList to a JTextField, however i do not want the person to be able to edit the text from the object after it has been put into the textfield.  I got the DnD to move,but only if the textfield is enabled, but if i do:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
field.setEnabled(false);
```

Then i can no longer drop the object into the textfield, also i only want one object to be in the field at a time,which is why i am not dragging into another JList.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to call `field.setFocusable(false);`

Answer (score 3):

One way: make the JTextField non-focusable via `field.setFocusable(false);`

This will allow the field to accept text but not allow the user to actually obtain its focus, preventing him from typing into the field.

Proof of concept code:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DragAndDropTest extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] LIST_DATA = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", 
            "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

    private JList<String> list = new JList<>(LIST_DATA);
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

    public DragAndDropTest() {
        list.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        textField.setFocusable(false); // *** here we go! ***
        textField.setTransferHandler(new MyTransferHandler());
        list.setPrototypeCellValue("abcdefghijkl");
        list.setDragEnabled(true);

        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        add(textField);
    }

    private class MyTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return COPY_OR_MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
            if (Arrays.asList(transferFlavors).contains(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
            // allow the JTextField's text to be *replaced* on drop
            try {
                String text = (String) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                ((JTextComponent) support.getComponent()).setText(text);
                return true;
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DragAndDrop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DragAndDropTest());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```